# Integral of $\int_{a}^b \sqrt{f(x)} \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have a differentiable positive function $f(x)$ and we know that
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^b f(x) dx= A
\end{align}
where $a>0$.
How to integrate the following expression 
\begin{align}
\int_{a}^b \sqrt{f(x)} \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}dx
\end{align}

I am trying to get a closed form expression only in terms of $A$. 
I think consecutive integration by parts might be the answer but so far I didn't have any luck.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you know $a>0$? Otherwise the second integral may not be finite at all (consider $f(x)=\sqrt x$).

Comment: yes. $a>0$ I will add. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such formula. Consider $f_m(x) = 1 + m(x-1)$ for $|m|$ small. Then

$$\int_{1/2}^{3/2} f_m(x)\ dx = 1$$

for all such $m.$ The other integral is

$$\tag 1 \int_{1/2}^{3/2} f_m(x)^{1/2}x^{-3/2}\ dx.$$

All I need to show is that $(1)$ is not independent of $m.$ How? Differentiate with respect to $m$ to get

$$\int_{1/2}^{3/2} (1/2)f_m(x)^{-1/2}(x-1)x^{-3/2}\ dx.$$

I didn't get much from that so I differentiated again to get

$$\tag 2 \int_{1/2}^{3/2} (-1/4)f_m(x)^{-3/2}(x-1)^2x^{-3/2}\ dx.$$

Now we're in business, because $(2)$ is strictly negative. That implies $(1)$ as a function of $m$ is strictly concave, hence is not constant.

Comment: Very nice answer! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: You're certainly welcome, to the both of you.